# Is there a way to get Amnesia The Dark Descent working on Ubuntu with an Inel HD integrated graphics card?

Tags: intel-graphics, games

Solved: Now you can run Amnesia even on computers which do not have external graphics card and have only Intel HD graphics card!

Why?
Amnesia needs S3TC support which the open source drivers that come with the OS do not support.

Installing libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 solves it!

Comment: If you are going to post an answer, please don't also update the question to include the answer or state "Solved" in the question. It is possible to accept your own answer as the answer, but you will have to wait a period of time before you can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

**Method 1 :**

Open Terminal

Copy and paste the following command

sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0

**Method 2 : The Hard Way**

First go to "Software Center".

Now search for **libtxc**.

Among the results install **"Texture compression library for Mesa"**.

**Now run Amnesia**. Set all graphics settings to low just to be sure. You can experiment with higher settings later.

Happy nightmares!